# External resources in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, movieclip, addchild

Hey all. I'm working on an application that was originally intended for HTML, but I've recently concluded that the best thing to do for my purposes is to do it in Flash instead.

One of the big things I need is to be able to bring in movieclips from external files and add them to my main movie at runtime (dynamic number of elements, skinning, etc.)

Don't need full-on code for this, but I could use some assistance in tracking down the resources to learn how to do these things successfully. Tutorials, best practices… The usual suspects.

I've been using Flash for a while now, and used to do this pretty easily in AS2, but I've had some hiccups using classes and addchild in an earlier attempt, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main tool for such things is [`flash.display.Loader`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html). It can load external images, movies and flash files and when it's loaded you can also access the properties of such (or the library, if you create it in the Flash IDE).

Comment: Will I be able to add the loaded swf elemnts via a loop after it's loaded?

Comment: Yeah, visible classes in the loaded swf file can be instantiated just like a local class.